# I want to pass the string that I got from the string to the onPostExecute method

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am New to the android studio and want to something more. Actually, I am trying to pass the string that I got from the spinner in onCreateMethod and pass to the onPostExecute function. I will be grateful for the help. Bellow is my code.

I tried making a global variable called First and store the string from spinner and pass it on the onPostExecute function.

```
 public class Convert extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener 
{
  Spinner dropdown;
  Button btn;
  String text;
  String first;

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);
    dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);

String[] items = new String[]{"United States,USD", "Nepal,NPR", "Bangladesh,BDT","Brazil,BRL"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            text = dropdown.getSelectedItem().toString();
            first = text.substring(text.length()-3);
            Log.i("her", first);
        }
    });
  new DownloadTask().execute("http://openexchangerates.org/api/latest.json? 
  app_id=XXXXXXXXXX");


}

public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {


        String result = "";

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

            int data = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char counter = (char) data;
                result += counter;

                data = reader.read();
            }

            return result;


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);



        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject curr = jsonObject.getJSONObject("rates");
            String npr = curr.getString(first);
            Log.i("money", npr );


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is to pass the string first on the onPostExecute function.

Answer (score 1):

When you will call your `DownloadTask`, asyncTask fires with method execute, just pass param though him. Example:

How to pass url

```
new DownloadTask().execute("url for download");
```

How to receive url

```
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    String url = urls[0]; // url for download
}
```

Also you could send and array of params. Also be careful with `AsyncTask`, do not pass your context/view variable, it could arise memory leaks, [read docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

Comment: I did that but I was trying to get the string from Spinner, Suppose when I press the button, I would get, "USD" and I want to pass that string on String npr = curr.getString(first); in onPostExecute function. :)